# Selecting A2DP changes nothing, what's a working conf file?

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, pulseaudio, bluetooth, a2dp

```
Xubuntu 14.04.3
Thinkpad t450s
Mpow Swift headset
$ bluetoothd -v
4.101
$ pulseaudio -v
4.0
```

A2DP was working (after following other threads to tweak the /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf file). I was able to disconnect and reconnect my headset previously. I would have to manually select A2DP instead of HFP/HSP, but it would work. I didn't change any versions or run a system update, but something happened because now it's not doing anything when I select A2DP. If 'Off' is selected, then selecting A2DP will result in no audio. If 'HFP/HSP' is selected, then selecting A2DP will result in still HFP/HSP output.

**Does anyone have a working setup to post their audio.conf, or any other files/settings, so I can match up what I have?**

**Is there a setting to have it select A2DP by default?**

**Thanks in advance!**

Here's my audio.conf. (I've tried enabling Socket - same result. I tried enabling HFP - same result.)

```
$ sudo cat /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf
# Configuration file for the audio service

# This section contains options which are not specific to any
# particular interface
[General]

# Switch to master role for incoming connections (defaults to true)
#Master=true

# If we want to disable support for specific services
# Defaults to supporting all implemented services
#Disable=Gateway,Source,Socket
#Enable=Gateway,Source
Enable=Source,Sink,Headset,Gateway,Control,Media
Disable=Socket

# SCO routing. Either PCM or HCI (in which case audio is routed to/from ALSA)
# Defaults to HCI
#SCORouting=PCM

# Automatically connect both A2DP and HFP/HSP profiles for incoming
# connections. Some headsets that support both profiles will only connect the
# other one automatically so the default setting of true is usually a good
# idea.
AutoConnect=true

# Headset interface specific options (i.e. options which affect how the audio
# service interacts with remote headset devices)
[Headset]

# Set to true to support HFP, false means only HSP is supported
# Defaults to true
HFP=false

# Maximum number of connected HSP/HFP devices per adapter. Defaults to 1
MaxConnected=1

# Set to true to enable use of fast connectable mode (faster page scanning)
# for HFP when incoming call starts. Default settings are restored after
# call is answered or rejected. Page scan interval is much shorter and page
# scan type changed to interlaced. Such allows faster connection initiated
# by a headset.
FastConnectable=false

# Just an example of potential config options for the other interfaces
[A2DP]
SBCSources=1
MPEG12Sources=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I tried changing to disable Headset and that killed it completely. The selections would just have (unplugged) after them so no audio would output:

```
Enable=Source,Sink,Gateway,Control,Media
Disable=Socket,Headset

$ sudo service bluetooth restart 
bluetooth stop/waiting
bluetooth start/running, process 8552
$ sudo alsa force-reload
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-seq snd-rawmidi snd-seq-device snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-intel snd-hda-controller snd-hda-codec snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-timer (failed: modules still loaded: snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-intel snd-hda-controller snd-hda-codec snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-timer).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-seq snd-rawmidi snd-seq-device snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-intel snd-hda-controller snd-hda-codec snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-timer.
$ pulseaudio -k
```

So then I put it back and it started working again:

```
Enable=Source,Sink,Gateway,Control,Media,Headset
Disable=Socket

$ sudo service bluetooth restart 
bluetooth stop/waiting
bluetooth start/running, process 15071
```

How that makes sense I don't know. Sometimes linux is the worst!

Comment: It was doing it again after being in suspended mode. I tried to just restart the bluetooth service and this time it worked with just that.
`sudo service bluetooth restart`

Comment: It's off and on working or not. These steps are now not fixing it. So it's random when it wants to work and when it doesn't.